# Can create BizTalk projects but not artifacts

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk, biztalk-2020

- Installed BizTalk 2020, did not configure
- Installed VS 2019 professional
- Installed BizTalk VSIX extensions.
- Rebooted.

It will let me create a BizTalk project, but when I go add new there's no way to create any BizTalk artifacts. Only choice available is a JSON application schema

I uninstalled it all and reinstalled, rebooted, nothing

I've been developing with BizTalk in earlier versions of vs, but never seen this problem

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was is BizTalk Developer Edition that you installed?

Comment: Also check what .Net version your project is targeting. Should be 4.7.2 or above

Answer (score 0):

With BizTalk 2020 you need to disable and enable the Visual studio extension so that the artifacts are loaded .. Flow the below steps and try out ..

o   Open Visual Studio 2019
o   From the Menu options --> Click Extensions--> Manage Extensions--> Installed--> AL --> BizTalk Server --> Click Disable

o   Close the Visual Studio

o   Repeat Step 1 to 3 , But this time Click Enable.

o   Close the Visual Studio and when u open the 3rd time you should be all set with the BizTalk templates and all the artifacts